# How to find if a key does not exist in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am importing some data from both a csv and an excel file using pandas, which are now dataframe types. And I am trying to use the csv to update the data in the excel file. I have the data being read correctly, but when I try to loop through the data to find if a certain key already exists, my if statement is not working.

```
for ID in update['Index']:
    if ID not in data['index']:
```

df1: data

```
Index Attr-1 Attr-2 Attr-3
01234 Blue   Car    Water
23456 Green  Truck  Lemonade
34567 Red    Bike   Milk Tea
```

df2: update

```
Index Attr-1 Attr-2 Attr-3
01234 Blue   Car    Milk Tea
34567 Yellow Truck  Lemonade
56789 Red    Bike   Milk Tea
```

actual result:

```
Index Attr-1 Attr-2 Attr-3
01234 Blue   Car    Milk Tea
01234 Blue   Car    Water
23456 Green  Truck  Lemonade
23456 Green  Truck  Lemonade
34567 Red    Bike   Milk Tea
34567 Yellow Truck  Lemonade
56789 Red    Bike   Milk Tea
```

desired result:

```
Index Attr-1 Attr-2 Attr-3
01234 Blue   Car    Milk Tea
23456 Green  Truck  Lemonade
34567 Yellow Truck  Lemonade
56789 Red    Bike   Milk Tea
```

My values are being duplicated because the values are not getting caught by the if statement. Not too sure what is going on? Any feedback/ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps `ID` is an integer in one data source, and a string in the other?  i.e. you're trying to compare integer `1234` to string `'1234'`, and of course those are not equal.

Comment: I did try and convert both ID and the data['index'] but it did not change the result.

Comment: Saying "I tried that but it didn't work" doesn't really tell us anything.  Show us __the actual code__ that you tried.

Comment: `for ID in update['index']:
    if str(ID) not in str(data['index']):`

Comment: If I understand your data structure correctly, that statement is comparing _keys_ to _values_.  (`ID` is a _key_, such as `1234`, but `data['index']` is a _value_, such as `['Green', 'Truck', 'Lemonade']`)

Comment: Sorry I think I must have put in something I was trying, but no I am trying to compare index to index, so data['index'] to update['index']

Comment: Hmm.  Perhaps that should actually work.  Can you show us the output of `print(data['index'])` and `print('update['index'])`?

Answer (score 2):

Please see if this works, you need to check for the ID in index:

```
>>> data = pd.DataFrame({'Attr-1':['Blue','Green','Red']},index=['01234','23456','34567'])                                              
>>> update = pd.DataFrame({'Attr-1':['Blue','Yellow','Green']},index=['01234','34567','56789'])                                         
>>> for ID in update.index:                                                                                                             
...     if ID not in data.index:                                                                                                        
...         data = data.append(update.loc[ID])                                                                                          
... 
>>> data
        Attr-1
01234   Blue
23456  Green
34567    Red
56789  Green
```

Comment: Sadly it gave me the same result :\

Comment: Can you send me the df which you have?

Comment: Not sure If I am allowed to share it. It's company data... What I put in the question is essentially what I am working with

Comment: The actual name for the key has spaces in it so I am using bracket notation.

Comment: @BrendenFujishige Reduce your code to the minimum that is needed to reproduce the issue, and replace any confidential data values with random data values if need be. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for some help on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The dataframe is not something I am allowed to use "in" on, which is why my for loop was not passing, so I created an array to hold the keys, data['index'].

```
`s = data['index'].tolist()
 for ID in update['index']:
  if ID not in s:`
```